# File & Printer Sharing not working on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, printer

When trying to share an existing printer i receive the following error message:

```
printer settings could not be saved. operation could not be completed (error 0x00000001)
```

I have already tried restarting the spooler and server service (including several reboots). I can access existing shares & printer but i am not able to create new ones.

When trying to share a folder i receive

```
an error occurred while trying to share <...>. Incorrect function. The shared resource was not created at this time.
```

the event viewer shows up the following:

```
source: printService, eventid: 315

The print spooler failed to share printer PXYZ with shared resource name PXYZ. Error 1. The printer cannot be used by others on the network.
```

The windows firewall is on for all profiles and the service is running - all connections are allowed. File and printer sharing is enabled under Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings for all profiles...

I have also completely deinstalled the running antivirus solution for testing purpose. However that did not make a difference.

In addition the following can be found in the log. I am not sure if this is of any relevance....

```
source: security-kerberos
eventi: 3

A Kerberos Error Message was received:
 on logon session 
 Client Time: 
 Server Time: 10:36:23.0000 2/18/2014 Z
 Error Code: 0xd KDC_ERR_BADOPTION
 Extended Error: 0xc00000bb KLIN(0)
 Client Realm: 
 Client Name: 
 Server Realm: TESTAD.DOMAIN.TLD
 Server Name: SERVER$@TESTAD.DOMAIN.TLD
 Target Name: SERVER$@TESTAD.DOMAIN.TLD@TESTAD.DOMAIN.TLD
 Error Text: 
 File: 9
 Line: f09
 Error Data is in record data.

source: security-kerberos
eventi: 3

A Kerberos Error Message was received:
 on logon session 
 Client Time: 
 Server Time: 10:38:20.0000 2/18/2014 Z
 Error Code: 0x7  KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN
 Extended Error: 
 Client Realm: 
 Client Name: 
 Server Realm: TESTAD.DOMAIN.TLD
 Server Name: HTTP/SOME_OTHER_SERVER.AD.DOMAIN.TLD
 Target Name: HTTP/SOME_OTHER_SERVER.AD.DOMAIN.TLD@TESTAD.DOMAIN.TLD
 Error Text: 
 File: 9
 Line: f09
 Error Data is in record data.
```

I am running out of ideas here. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this: `I opened the "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" and clicked the "Restore defaults" button, and that solved the problem, and I can now share files again.`...sounds like more than one person online found this to fix the issue.  But...you could look and just make sure file and print sharing in the Windows advanced firewall has the right settings (check another 2008 server for details) before going to a full reset of the defaults.  I'd backup the firewall config/settings first too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That fixed my issue. How can i mark your comment as an answer to my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: I opened the "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" and clicked the "Restore defaults" button, and that solved the problem, and I can now share files again.  You could also do this from the command line:

```
netsh advfirewall reset
```

....sounds like more than one person online found this to fix the issue. But...you could look and just make sure file and print sharing in the Windows advanced firewall has the right settings (check another 2008 server for details) before going to a full reset of the defaults. I'd backup the firewall config/settings first too.